# Updating rows in a ResultSet from an inner join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have tables `A` and `B`, they each have the same primary key (Col1).

```
Table A                     Table B
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3       Col 1 | Col 4
```

I'd like to update rows in table `B` based on information from the corresponding row in table `A`.  If I were to get a result set with an inner join on the two tables,

`select A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, B.Col4 from A inner join B on A.Col1=B.Col1;`

Could I iterate through this result set and update Col4 in Table B? That is, using the JDBC/ResultSet updateX(...) methods?

The reason I ask is because, it seems a bit strange, to update table B from the result set A join B.

---

**Clarification:** Not sure if this will matter, but I'm interested in updating the rows via the JDBC ResultSet interface, not a direct MySQL update query. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: You can update via a JOIN -- but what do you want to update the value to be?

Comment: Some features of JDBC are not always implemented by database vendors.

Comment: @sgeddes: There's a string in Col3 that I need to match with Regex, and depending on the match, update Col4.

Comment: @Paul Vargas: the vendor is MySQL

Comment: same question needed. DBServer: MariaDB 5.5.38, JDBC: mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar. All two tables have primary keys, and the result set is get from CallableStatement, and the procedure select data from two tables. and the error:  Result Set not updatable (referenced table has no primary keys).This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to update TableB using a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE TableB B
    JOIN TableA A ON B.Col1=A.Col1
SET B.Col4 = 'Some Value'
WHERE A.Col2 REGEXP 'Some Regex'
```

Not knowing what Regex you want to use and in what scenario, and what value you want to update Col4 to, makes it a little difficult, but this should be pretty close.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/575ec/1)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
UPDATE
    B
INNER JOIN
    A ON B.id=A.id 
SET
    B.value=A.value
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85d5c/1)

This is a skeleton, update other columns of B according to your needs.

Comment: Most likely the question is about using the update functionality of the Java `ResultSet`, where you update through the resultset without issuing the query yourself (either the driver does it for you, or the database supports updatable resultsets)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ahh, ktm5124 has added this clarification after I provided the answer

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this one looking for the scenario where I wanted to transform some data and move it between tables.

There is a two pass workaround, but it involves creating temporary columns.

- first in the target table, create a temporary column of the fields needed in the transformation
- second, use a simple SQL update to populate those columns from the other table
- third use an updateable result set to do the transformation you initially wanted to do
- lastly remove the temporary columns